# Appending CRC (Checksum) to data stream serial port communication C++

Tags: c++, checksum, crc

I am appending CRC to a data stream. I am using a serial port libary from RS-232 for Linux and Windows.

I want to get the same value as the one displayed on the comport tool picture:

[image: Serialport communcation from a comport tool]

I am using `const char[4086]="123456789";` as buffer.

CRC returned is bb3d which I then convert from `unsigned short` to `char *`.

```
#define SERIALPORT_BUFSIZE       4088

char *im_buf = (char *)malloc(SERIALPORT_BUFSIZE  + 8);

char *tx_buf = (char *)malloc(SERIALPORT_RCV_BUFSIZE  + 8);

const char buf[SERIALPORT_BUFSIZE]="123456789";

strcpy(im_buf, buf);
WriteToSerialPort(); // call to function

void SerialPortCom::WriteToSerialPort(void)
{
    if(!port_open) return;

    int i,n, tmp, tmp2;

    if(newline == 1)
    {
        strcat(im_buf, "0a");
    }
    else if(newline == 2)
    {
        strcat(im_buf, "0d");
    }
    else if(newline == 3)
    {
        strcat(im_buf, "0d0a");
    }

    n = strlen(im_buf) / 2;

    if(n < 1) return;

    for(i=0; i< n; i++)
    {
        tmp = im_buf[i*2];

        if((tmp >= '0') && (tmp <= '9'))
        {
            tmp -= '0';
        }
        else if((tmp >= 'a') && (tmp <= 'f'))
        {
            tmp -= ('a' - 10);
        }
        else if((tmp >= 'A') && (tmp <= 'F'))
        {
            tmp -= ('A' - 10);
        }

        tmp *= 16;

        tmp2 = im_buf[(i*2)+1];

        if((tmp2 >= '0') && (tmp2 <= '9'))
        {
            tmp2 -= '0';
        }
        else if((tmp2 >= 'a') && (tmp2 <= 'f'))
        {
            tmp2 -= ('a' - 10);
        }
        else if((tmp2 >= 'A') && (tmp2 <= 'F'))
        {
            tmp2 -= ('A' - 10);
        }

        tmp += tmp2;

        tx_buf[i] = tmp;

    }
    //generate crc
    unsigned short crc  = GetCrc16(im_buf, strlen(im_buf));
    //append crc
    memcpy( tx_buf + n, &crc, 2 );
    //send to serial port
    RS232_SendBuf(comport_nr, (unsigned char *)tx_buf, n+2);

}
```

What I get:     (`12 34 56 78 70 11 4A 3D`)
What I want:(`12 34 56 78 7B 34 FD FD FD FD`)

How to achieve the expected result?

```
unsigned short SerialPortCom::GetCrc16(const char* InStr,unsigned int len)
{
    //Crc16
    unsigned short Crc16Table[256];
    unsigned int i,j;
    unsigned short Crc;      
    unsigned char CRCHigh = 0xFF, CRCLow = 0xFF;

    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        Crc = i;
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            if(Crc & 0x1)
                Crc = (Crc >> 1) ^ 0xA001;
            else
                Crc >>= 1;
        }
        Crc16Table[i] = Crc;
    }
    //CRC16
    Crc=0x0000;
    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        Crc = (Crc >> 8) ^ Crc16Table[(Crc & 0xFF) ^(uint8_t) InStr[i]];

    }
    //Crc ^= 0x0000;

    return Crc;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, some notes :

- Your inputs are ASCII hex. Each character is a half-byte, but your input string has an odd number of characters : you discard the last character.
- What you expect is `12 34 56 78 7B 34` : `0x347B` is the CRC for `0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78`. The additional `FD`s looks like some irrelevant end of buffer (or another bug ?).

The problems with your program :

You need a data buffer to send with `RS232_SendBuf`. You convert your ASCII to data and put it in `tx_buf` and then you take its CRC. That's fine, but you use `strcat` to append the CRC to the buffer ; you can't do that, `strcat` is for text. `strcat` expect two null terminated strings, but you have two data buffers.

You CRC function has a problem too : you have a superfluous mask `& 0x7F` that removes the last bit of each CRC byte. The `0xFF` mask is sufficient (and not even needed actually).

You also allocate a buffer with `new char[2]`, but never `delete` it. That will work but it's ugly.

Note that your CRC is just two bytes ; just return `Crc` directly as an `unsigned short`.

After that, just append your CRC to your buffer with `memcpy`.
In your case, that would be `memcpy( tx_buf + n, &my_crc_short, 2 );`

Comment: thanks for your timely response,  i have included my crc function,  i will appreciate if you could give me an example . to ways i can attach the crc i have being on this for two weeks now. thanks

Comment: @MelFzllc Edited my answer.

Comment: thank you @elderbug your example is very insightful. i have edited my question to reflect what i understood from your pointers. however i am still not getting the value `7B34` i am getting  `3D BB` with `char *im_buf` and various value with `char *tx_buf `. any pointers thanks for being so helpful

Comment: @MelFzllc That's because you actually calculate the CRC of the ASCII text "123456789", when you want the CRC of the data (`0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78`). You need to make the CRC for `tx_buf`, of size `n`.

Comment: by CRC for `tx_buf`, of size `n` do you mean this ` unsigned short crc  = GetCrc16(tx_buf, strlen(tx_buf));` `RS232_SendBuf(comport_nr, (unsigned char *)tx_buf, n+2);` right? thanks for your patience and timely response i still get varing crc,

Comment: @MelFzllc `tx_buf` is not a string, so you can't use `strlen`. Your `tx_buf` contains raw data, and you already have the length of this data in `n`.

Comment: oh! thank you so very much, May God bless you richly. i am so very grateful. thanks for your timely response... you have saved me three weeks for try to figure thing out

Comment: i tried the code on a full deployment but i got different values can you throw some like this is my first experience dealing with serial port comunication code used `FA02030A3` got `FA 02 03 0A 21 37` instead of `FA 02 03 0A 11 6F` any pointers modified code `unsigned short crc  = GetCrc16(tx_buf, n);
    int crclength = (sizeof(&crc)/sizeof(short));

    memcpy(tx_buf + n, &crc, crclength );

    RS232_SendBuf(comport_nr, (unsigned char *)tx_buf, (n+crclength));`

Comment: @MelFzllc To get the length of `crc`, just use `sizeof(crc)`. `sizeof(&crc)/sizeof(short)` means size of a pointer divided by size of a short, which is non-sense. Your problem is in your CRC function, when you do `(Crc & 0xFF) ^ InStr[i]`. `InStr[i]` is a signed char, so when you xor it, it is sign-extended, so `^ int(char(0xFA))` is actually `^ 0xFFFFFFFA`. Use an unsigned type (`uint8_t` is good). Whenever you manipulate raw data, use unsigned types.

Comment: thank you for your patience and pointers , are you sugessting a rewrite of the function to return `uint8_t`? a friend of mine sent me the above function which gave this `FA 02 03 0A 11 EF` instead of `FA 02 03 0A 11 6F`

Comment: @MelFzllc No, `InStr` needs to be typed with an unsigned type to avoid sign extension. The function is fine except this point. You need to either change the parameter type, or cast `InStr` to `uint8_t` (`(uint8_t)InStr[i]`). As it is now, the function doesn't work if any value is greater than `0x7F` (so it worked fine with `0x78`, but it doesn't with `0xFA`).

Comment: thanks for you timely response, i tried casting as you suggest am getting `FA 02 03 0A 11 EF` instead of `FA 02 03 0A 11 6F` just like the function i added to the question, what could i be missing

Comment: @MelFzllc `11 EF` is the correct CRC for `FA 02 03 0A`. If you have something else, this thing is wrong. Maybe this has to do with the `& 0x7F` mask you had before ? This would mean you use a truncated CRC. Try to CRC `00 00 00 01`, this should give `C1 C0`. If you get `41 40` then you are missing the 8th bits. If you really want it like this, just return `crc & 0x7F7F` instead of `crc`.

Comment: thanks for your time in putting me through this serial port programming. i will like to contact you to mentor me in programming c++ as your time will spare if you dont mind.. thanks again for coming to my rescue

Comment: i need help in reviewing my complete code, will also need help on packed BCD can you help?